# Alter add to cart message

Tags: commerce

How to alter the message shown - "xyz" added to your cart, when we add an item to cart in Drupal 8 Commerce 2x.

I saw `Drupal\commerce_cart\EventSubscriber` where the function `displayAddToCartMessage(CartEntityAddEvent $event)` is written which is responsible for showing the message, is there any method to override it.

Answer (score 0):

Install the *Commerce Extended Quantity* module and then implement a **HOOK_xquantity_add_to_cart_qty_prices_msg_alter()**:
https://github.com/drugan/commerce_xquantity#an-item-added-to-your-cart-message-alter